# How can I call websocket server onMessage function from other PHP file?

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I am using websocket for broadcast message to all connected user.
My queries is can I call `onMessage()` function from any other PHP file
`onMessage()` function is within `Chat` class.

My main concern is when database update from outside of my server (using sync from anywhere) then I want to send this new changes to all server connected user.

Let me know any way so I can do it.

This is my **Chat.php** file of rachet websocket

```
    namespace Chat;

    use Chat\Repository\ChatRepository;
    use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
    use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {

    protected $repository;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->repository = new ChatRepository;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
       conection open code..
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->repository->removeClient($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
       error code...
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $msg) {

        $data = $this->parseMessage($msg);
        foreach ($this->repository->getClients() as $client) {
                $client->sendMsg($data->msg);
        }
    }

    private function parseMessage($msg) {
        return json_decode($msg);
    }

}
```

I am using codeigniter so above is library class file.
Now i want to call this `onMessage()` from another controller file.
Can i do it ?
If yes then how can i get `connectionInterface` in controller file ?

Comment: You may need to better explain your structure of servers and php instances ..

Comment: @Berniev please have a look and let me know if you want to more detail...